# Why does iPad always write a Spotlight folder to my Cam SD cards

Tags: ios

Very annoying as it takes up space on the card, is there any way of stopping this?  Haven’t been able to find anything relevant in settings.

Comment: The deleted answer below was essentially correct. Your response was unfortunately unfriendly towards someone only trying to help. You can partially prevent this on Mac, though only for Spotlight, none of the other metadata. The footprint is tiny & the information is hidden by default on Apple systems. Other operating systems may not know what it is & may display it openly. There is no simple way to deal with this.

Comment: The response might have been technically correct if I possessed a Mac but I specifically asked the question regarding an iPad.  My apologies for being liverish.  I mostly use Win 10 and Ubuntu for lap/desk use and iPad/iphone for mobile, just annoying that the iPad puts unnecessary stuff on SDs.

Comment: You're on an Apple-oriented site, so it wasn't an extraordinary sideways leap. Nix ought to consider these as simply hidden files, dot-prefixed. Windows I don't know so well, it tends to do its own thing - maybe it's equable to the desktop.ini files it seems to throw everywhere at will;). Mainly, though, this hasn't been actually preventable on macOS since "OS X 10.0" so I very much doubt its new inclusion in iPadOS is going to make any changes in that respect.